# AngularJS directive with callback in scope prevents other directives from working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a directive with an isolated scope:

```
directive("myDirective",function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {aaa: '='},
        link: function(scope, elem) { }
    };
})
```

The directive works well, but it prevents all other dierctives on the same element from working...

I've reproduced the problem on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ironshay/k5ndr/

I'm using angular 1.0.7.

Am I doing something wrong? or is it some kind of an angular bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you've created a child scope by using scope: {} on the directive. So the foo variable isn't on that scope anymore, it's on the parent. By using $parent.foo everything works correctly:

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="with directive" ng-disabled="!$parent.foo || $parent.foo == ''" my-directive func="myFunc()" />
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/k5ndr/2/

Answer (score 1):

You are creating isolated scope, which i think is causing the other directives also to get the isolated scope.

You can try to pass the foo variable to the isolated scope as you did the `myFunc` function.

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="with directive" foo='foo' ng-disabled="!foo || foo == ''" my-directive func="myFunc()" />
```

I tried to create a fiddle for the same

http://jsfiddle.net/njXjj/